# Android Activity stop due to non-working toast

Tags: java, android, android-activity, toast

Hello Stack Overflow !

I'm working on an android application for children : Each activity is a question.
For each question, there is two buttons for clue and the answer.
I encounter two issues :
1/ I have to click on a button before change activity, do I need an override or something so I can change of activity without any click required ?
2/ On this activity (code is below), if I click on the button with the id "essai", the activity stop and I came to the previous activity.. Anybody know how I could fix this ?
  *Thank you in advance !*

Here is the java code

```
 package com.beryl.timewaster;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.ImageButton;
  import android.widget.Toast;

   public class Activity1 extends Activity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);
}

public void indice1(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "expression", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void indice2(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "aguéri", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void essai(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "LOLILO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    final ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flechegauche1);
  ib2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Accueil.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

    });
          }}
```

And here the xml

```
   <AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_x="-1dp"
        android:layout_y="61dp"
        android:text="@string/dev2"
        android:textColor="@color/blanc"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:color="@color/blanc" />

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/Solution2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="259dp"
        android:onClick="essai"
        android:text="@string/solution"
        android:textColor="@color/vertpomme"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

   <Button
     android:id="@+id/indice1de2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="1dp"
        android:layout_y="121dp"
        android:onClick="indice1"
        android:text="@string/indice1"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/indice2de2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="190dp"
        android:onClick="indice2"
        android:text="@string/indice2"
        android:textColor="@color/rouge"
        android:textSize="30sp" />>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flechedroite2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="196dp"
        android:layout_y="338dp"
        android:src="@drawable/flechedroite" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flechegauche2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="33dp"
        android:layout_y="339dp"
        android:src="@drawable/flechegauche" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the essai method ? Also, please post the Logcat stack trace of the error you're facing. Finally, can you be more explicit on how/when you want the second activity to open ?

Comment: As @2Dee said: noone is going to help you without the stack trace. Also, why do set your ClickListener not inside `onCreate` of your Activity. It is also not a good Practice to have one Activity for one Question. Depending on the count of your questions you easyly get to more than 100 Activitys which is complete Overhead! You are forced to define ANY Activity inside a Manifest. Better would be to have a `QuestionModel` that is chainable, whih ONE QuestionActivity is using! Furthermore I'm quite shure that your problem has NOTHING to do with the `Toast`you are showing!

Comment: Thanks for your remarks ! I need to go back home for the logcat, but this will be ok in a couple hours ! Rafael, could you please give me a link or a short explanation about how could  I define a model and change the questions, hint and answers ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Allow me to answer that : one Activity, one layout file for it, containing 3 texViews(1 for the question, 1 for hint, 1 for the answer) and relevant buttons. Use the onClick methods of your buttons to hide/show the answer TextViews, or change the text of the question. Use resources to store your questions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

Change `final ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flechegauche1);` to `final ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flechegauche2);`. You have not declared `android:id="@+id/flechegauche1"` in your xml